# Replacing values in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R - incompatible types

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, spatial, r-sp

I am using the `sp` package in R to do a fairly simple aggregation of point attributes in polygons (i.e. `SpatialPointsDataFrame` in `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`). I believe I can do this with no problem. However, in an attempt to make "prettier" plots, I want to replace areas aggregated where no points occurred (given NAs after using the `aggregate` function) with the number 0. When I do this, I receive the error:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = ) : 
  incompatible types (from S4 to double) in subassignment type fix

See reproducible code below. I'm working with the state of Washington so I decided to continue in my example:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

### Get Washington County map ###
USCounty <- raster::getData('GADM', country='USA', level=2) # Download US County Map
WA <- USCounty[USCounty$NAME_1 == "Washington",] # Subset data to just the State of WA

### Create point data ###

# Set parameters
numPts <- 30 # Set the number of points

# Set projection I want
ptsCRS <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# Project data
WA <- spTransform(WA, ptsCRS)

# Create point coordinates and attribute data
set.seed(22)
x <- sample(xmin(WA):xmax(WA), numPts, replace = TRUE) #xvalues in the extent of the state
y <- sample(ymin(WA):ymax(WA), numPts, replace = TRUE) #yvalues in the extent of the state
ptsCoords <- cbind(x,y) # Store the coordinates
ptsData <- data.frame(Att = rnorm(numPts, 7, 1)) # Create and store attribute data

pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(ptsCoords, data = ptsData, proj4string = crs(WA))

# Plot the data
plot(WA)
plot(pts, add = TRUE)

### Perform Aggregation of point attributes by WA polygons ###
countyAgg <- aggregate(pts[WA, "Att"], WA, sum)

### Plot Data ###
spplot(countyAgg)
```

[image]

The plot is what I want, however, I would like to have the "empty" polygons be treated as the number 0. I see that the "empty" polygons are NAs

Therefore I did:

```
# Find NAs
naIndex <- which(is.na(countyAgg$Att))

# Replace with zeroes
countyAgg[naIndex,]$Att <- 0
```

And I obtain the error:

> incompatible types (from S4 to double) in subassignment type fix.

Can anyone help my situation, and/or offer an alternative method for any aspect of my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `countyAgg[naIndex, "Att"] <- 0`

The difference can be seen in the following statements:

```
R> class(countyAgg[naIndex,]$Att)
[1] "numeric"
R> class(countyAgg[naIndex, "Att"])
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple. I really appreciate the help!